# How to read a particular row in CSV file

Tags: java, csv, selenium-webdriver

I have an arraylist that I want to verify with the rows of a csv file.
Everytime the arraylist has different elements as I am creating that arraylist dynamically and adding element text from my webpage. But I wanna access the csv data horizontally i.e. everytime I want to veryfy the row data with my arraylist. Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (path))){
        Stream<String> lines = br.lines();
        String[] linesArray = lines.toArray();            

        if (index < linesArray.length) {

            String line = linesArray[index];
            //then you can do your verification
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is throwing 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that stream can only be used once, I will edit the answer

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: thanks for your help but I found some other solution